# html entities for utf-8 character in php

Tags: php

I have used html_entities for UTF-8 in php.

```
$input = "<div> 'Testing' </div>";

echo htmlentities($input,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

But, above encoding is working for normal input, if i give below input and use encoding then I am getting blank output.

```
$input = "<div>Other 'user' is working on this line. Please contribute the next line.</div>";

echo htmlentities($input,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

I dont know how this is giving blank output.
If i print $input then I am getting below value in $input.

```
<div>Other user working on this line.�Please contribute the next line.</div>
```

Is any thing missed in htmlentities code, Please folks provide your suggestions.

Thanks,

-Pravin.

Comment: What encoding do you have your files in? Where does that data come from? Db? If yes, what encoding in DB in? What charset does your HTML have?

Comment: I am getting this $input from file. I am reading file line by line and then executing above code for each line.

Comment: Where is the source of the file?

Comment: in my local machine...from UI end I have used upload feature through which user will upload file and that file I am extracting....

Comment: Try post the original context of the file (the line contains the problem will do)

Comment: Your input seems to be containing a non-UTF-8 character.

Comment: My problem with blank output concerning UTF8 encoding is that there seems to be corrupt non-visible entity in your input... My solution is notepad++ and switch the encoding over a few times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing $input to utf8_encode first, and then passing the data to htmlentities with only the ENT_NOQUOTES option set:

```
<?php

$input = "<div>Other 'user' is working on this line. Please contribute the next line.</div>";
echo htmlentities(utf8_encode($input),ENT_NOQUOTES);

?>
```